# Is there a way to auto-upload photos to Flickr on Mac?

Tags: dropbox, flickr

I'm using Dropbox as my primary auto-upload tool from iOS, and I'd like to streamline the process of getting photos to Flickr. Rather than using the Flickr iOS app's built in auto-upload, I'd like to only upload the photos once (via Dropbox) and then have something monitor the Camera Uploads folder on the Mac for new files.

Is there a tool that monitors a folder on a Mac and uploads any newly added photos to Flickr with privacy set to private?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I found a new solution. It's an app called UPPR. It is [currently $2.99USD on the Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/uppr-an-uploader-for-flickr/id810276003?mt=12). The app is simple and great, I use it now to monitor my OneDrive (switched from DropBox) pictures folder. It passively monitors a folder and uploads anything in it to Flickr. Super easy. You can set tags and privacy for all uploads.

Answer (score 3):

For an OS-independent solution, the following [IFTTT](http://ifttt.com) recipe looks like it will do what you need.

[Upload to dropbox - push through to flickr](https://ifttt.com/recipes/6804-upload-to-dropbox-push-through-to-flickr)

In a nutshell, the recipe monitors a specific folder in Dropbox (the recipe uses "/Flickr", but you can change that) and uses the "[Upload public photo from URL](https://ifttt.com/channels/flickr/actions/18-upload-public-photo-from-url)" action on the Flickr channel to upload the image.

There are a [number of recipes that use Dropbox and Flickr](https://ifttt.com/recipes/search?q=dropbox+flickr&ac=false), so even if this one isn't exact (and you don't want to customize) you should be able to find one you want. Here's another possiblity: [Move Dropbox photos from Camera Uploads folder to flickr gallery](https://ifttt.com/recipes/95380-move-dropbox-photos-from-camera-uploads-folder-to-flickr-gallery).

Comment: Thank you for the well researched answer! I've looked into the IFTTT option but my reservation is that uploaded photos default to public on Flickr. That's my interpretation of the recipe.

Comment: @Elliott: If you don't want the photos to be uploaded to your public photostream that's an important bit of information that should be in your question post.

Answer (score 0):

See this, http://www.picbackman.com/picbackman-for-mac-os/ You can automate the process of uploading photos from Mac to your Dropbox account. The desktop app also keeps a check on new additions. As soon as you upload new photos to your iPhoto library, the PicBcakMan desktop application will automatically upload it to Dropbox account.

Give it a try.